# Losing id (primary key) value stored in a List from DAO to Business through an EJB

Tags: mysql, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.0, eclipse-jee

I want to display a list of users in an XHTML page. I'm sending a request from my managedBean to the Business through an EJB (3.0) then another request to the DAO still through an EJB (3.0). I'm using JPA 2 and a MySQL database with an entity manager.

I'm sending the following request to my database

```
@Remote(IDaoUser.class)
@Stateless
Public class DaoUser implements IDaoUser

@PersitenceContext(unitName = "persistence_unit")
Private EntityManager em;

@Override
Public List<User> getAll() {
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u");
    List<User> users = query.getResultList();
    return users;
}
```

At that point everything's fine and I get all my users in my list with all attributes especially id (primary key). My user class has one attribute (birthdate) and inherits from a super class Parent (name, forename, mail, phone...) which inherits again from another class called Who which has just one attribute called id (the primary key).
Then I return my List (users) to the business through an EJB and once in the business I realise all the id attributes are 0. I kept all the others attributes (name, forename...) except ids and I can't figure out why I'm losing these values.
There are well stored in my List in the DAO but all changed to 0 once in the business.

Here is my business class which is very simple

```
@Remote(IBusinessUser.class)
@Stateless
Public class BusinessUser implements IBusinessUser

@EJB
private IDaoUser proxy;

@Override
Public List<User> getAll() {
    List<User> users = proxy.getAll();
    return users;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the description of the problem, I would ask some questions

1. Are the parent classes entities themselves, i.e. are they annotated with @Entity.
2. You need to ensure that @Id  is on your primary key. Do you have the @Id annotation on the primary key.

Experience has taught me to always have the @Id attribute in class or at least in a parent class tagged with the @MappedSuperclass. And some people still have problems with retrieving their id fields from the mapped super class.

So see the JEE documentation for using the [MappedSuperclass](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/MappedSuperclass.html) annotation. This may require changing your object inheritance model but that shouldn't be a problem given your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. Actually both parent classes are themselves entities. My super class "Who" is the only one having an id attribute (primary key) with the annotation @Id. I can't tag my super class with the @MappedSuperclass since it is associated to another class.